# Escaping double-quotes vs. single-quotes

Tags: python, git, github

I noticed this code:

```
os.system("'{0}'".format(path))
```

and saw that some one had change it to this:

```
os.system("\"{0}\"".format(path))
```

I was wondering by changing it from single to double quotes what advantages does it give you?

Here is the original commit I pulled it from: https://github.com/mattn/legit/commit/84bd1b1796b749a7fb40e0b734d2de29ddc9d3d9

Comment: Is this a Python question?

Comment: You wonder what advantage is has? It will output the string as they want, wrapped in double-quotes, not in single quotes. And, this isn't a Ruby or Rails question, so I removed their tags.

Comment: ok sorry about that was clicking around quite a bit but yes I was wondering what was going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much really but rule of thumb use single quotes for literal assignments and prints. That way you will avoid printing things that shouldn't be there in the first place.

Single quotes are often useful because they are  literal, and contain exactly the characters you type e.g. **'Hi there/'** will actually print **Hi there/**

However, if you need something like **'Hi there /n'**, if you put it in single quotes it will give you literally **'Hi there /n'** whereas double quotes will give you the result you need **"Hi there" and then break line**.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand they do this because they are saying there is no dynamic content?

Comment: I'm not a Python expert but here's what I think for the above. The first example with single quotes it will literal pass the square brackets {} as part of the argument. Whereas the double quotes will pass the representation of the square brackets. String interpolation is similar in Ruby. Double quotes will interpolate "#{@user}" where single quotes '{@user}' will not. I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the response I think this explains what I am asking the best.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, command line arguments are parsed by the program it-self, not shell or cmd.exe. And most of windows programs parse quoted strings with double quote in generally. `python.exe` is the same. On unix OSs, command line arguments are parsed by shell. And most of shells parse single/double quote both. of course, double quote expand `$` or something which the shell can treat. However, path will not contains `$`.

This change is workaround to be possible to work legit on many OSs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: oh wow did not know that about python. Thanks for the input. it really helps because I am coming from ruby on rails and going to more python programing. I also was explained to me that single quotes which is this = '. I means in ruby you can't call a result like "#{happy_string}" I found out if you try to make this same call using single quotes it will not work in ruby. '#{}

Comment: sorry did not finish last comment. it will not work in ruby '#{happy_string}' because it will consider it a as what it is. rather then substitues #{happy_string} with what ever happy_string is. It is kind of hard to explain.